# Complex subject

Tags: word-usage, phrase-usage, compound-subjects

Someone argued with me on this phrase.

> The most important reason for studying abroad which helps to develop self confidence because you are always alone.

I told him this was a wrong sentence as the whole sentence before "because" seems to me as a subject without verb. and I corrected like this:

> The most important reason of studying abroad is to develop self confidence...

am I right? Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

I think they're both kind of clunky. Here's my take on your sentence:

> The most important reason to study abroad is that it will help you develop self-confidence because you are always alone.

With the word *reason*, it's better to use the infinitive form of a verb and then introduce the actual reason using the construction *is that*.

As for the semantics, I'm not really sure what you mean by *because you are always alone*, to tell you the truth.